# Is 1-(1-Methyl cyclopropyl) carbocation [1] as stable as Cyclopropyl Methyl Carbocation[2]

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, carbocation

Does the extra Methyl group interfere with the exceptional stability of Cyclopropyl Methyl Carbocation?[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]
As you can clearly see in the canonical structures,
The extra methyl group stabilizes 1 by positive inductive effect. Hence 1 is more stable than 2